# Why does the backward recursion work better?

Tags: numerical-methods

Computing the following integral:
\begin{equation*}
I_n = \int_0^1 x^n e^x \: dx,
\end{equation*}
using the **forward recursive** formula
\begin{align}
I_0 &= e-1 \\
I_{n} &= e - n I_{n-1}
\end{align}
is an unstable calculation. Here we will consider a different approach that is stable.

Solve Equation (2) for $I_{n-1}$ to give a **backwards recursive formula** (one that expresses $I_{n-1}$ as a function of $I_n$).

$I_{n-1} = \frac{e-I_{n}}{n}$

Running both the recursion formulas in my MatLab program gives the following results

[the unstable recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPsrb.png) [the rewritten stable recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sklo.png)

What I don't know how to answer is why does the backward recursive formula work so much better than the forward recursive formula? What is happening to the numerical error?

Answer (score 3):

Assume a numerical error at step $n$ to be $\Delta_n$. Assume that the error in $e$ is $0$. Then using the forward formula, the error is increasing in absolute value: $$\Delta_n^F=n\Delta_{n-1}^F$$ In the backward formula $$\Delta_n^B=\frac1n\Delta_{n-1}^B$$
You can see that the backward value gets more precise.